# Is it possible to set up a project alert for a TFS site collection

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

Is it possible to set up an email project alert for the entire TFS collection or do they need to be created for each individual project in the collection?

I have tons of projects in my site collection and would like an email to be sent to our dev team every time a build of any project completes...

Maybe there is an easy way to do this with the alerts explorer (from the TFS powertools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found out how to do this:

```
1) Create a new project alert on any project.
2) Open alerts explorer (Team > Alerts Explorer)
3) Remove the Team Project Filter as in the screenshot below:
4) Watch in awe as you get emailed whenever any project in your site collection completes a build.
```

[image]